# Есть ли проблемы с new this?

Tags: javascript

https://github.com/lahmatiy/es6-promise-polyfill/blob/master/promise.js

```
Promise.reject = function(reason){
  var Class = this;

  return new Class(function(resolve, reject){
    reject(reason);
  });
};
```

Зачем нужна промежуточная переменная `Class`, почему бы не сделать просто

```
Promise.reject = function(reason){
  return new this(function(resolve, reject){
    reject(reason);
  });
};
```

Связано ли это как-то с поддержкой старых браузеров, или же автор просто решил, что в таком виде код становится понятнее?

---

Посмотрел минифицированный вариант - в нём спокойно пишется `new this`.

Comment: скорее всего, чтобы показать что `this` тут не объект, а функция, для минифицированного варианта это не важно, так как обычно разбирают не минифицированную версию

Comment: @Grundy, я просто не сразу догадался в минифицированный вариант заглянуть. А вообще, вроде и так ясно, что `this` там - это сам `Promise`.

Comment: конечно не ясно :-) `new Promise.reject` и уже не `Promise`

Comment: @Grundy, но ведь такой вызов логику работы попортит. Да и вообще, ты часто у конструктора видишь статические поля с другими конструкторами? Это как-то странновато :)

Comment: это другой вопрос :) но точную причину только автор знает :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поскольку в минифицированном варианте спокойно пишется `new this`, считаю, что переменная в коде заведена просто по желанию автора (который, вероятно,  посчитал, что так читаемее).